# Camera movements in Verold

Tags: verold

In Verold, using the Verold Studio controls, how do I get the camera to rotate around the axis of the model when I pan, rather than just turning on its own axis? I've searched through the controls in Studio and am unable to find the solution. I am certain it is right in front of me, I just cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the camera, then open orbit controls, and the first setting in there is the object to orbit. You can set this to a model, or a mesh. Depending on what you want to orbit.

The other trick is that you should make sure that your camera's initial position is a valid orbit position. To do this, select the model you want to orbit and click the 'F' key. Now you can choose your camera and set it to this position using the "align to position" button.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but when I double click the default camera and the Inspector opens, I cannot see any setting to select the object to orbit.